# How to download Oracle JDK from command line on Docker

Tags: java, linux, docker, command-line, centos

I'm trying to download the oracle JDK 8 using command line for installation on a centos base image.
Running

```
wget --no-cookies --no-check-certificate --header "Cookie: gpw_e24=http%3a%2F%2Fwww.oracle.com%2Ftechnetwork%2Fjava%2Fjavase%2Fdownloads%2Fjdk8-downloads-2133151.html; oraclelicense=accept-securebackup-cookie;" "https://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u191-b12/2787e4a523244c269598db4e85c51e0c/jdk-8u191-linux-x64.tar.gz"
```

comes back with

> HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found

**I tried** using curl as well and both methods just seem to download a html page.

```
curl -L -C - -b 'oraclelicense=accept-securebackup-cookie' -o /tmp/java.tar.gz http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u201-b09/42970487e3af4f5aa5bca3f542482c60/server-jre-8u201-linux-x64.tar.gz
```

Comment: As you tagged `alpine`: Even if your download succeeds, the regular JRE will not work on alpine, as you're the underlying libc is `musl` and not `glibc`. Use the alpine built openjdk8 packages instead: [pkgs.alpinelinux.org](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/packages?name=openjdk8*&branch=edge&arch=x86_64)

Comment: @bratkartoffel I am required to use oracle jdk only. I'm actually building a docker image. Which OS do you recommend I use for this?

Comment: You may not use OpenJDK (which is also from oracle)? Then I'd suggest using `ubuntu` or `debian` as base image